# backup and restore mysql from php code

Tags: php, mysql

i use php on **windows** , how can i backup mysql to a compressed file so restore from it using php code

thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading [this.](http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html)  Personally i would just use phpMyAdmin to export the db as a zip file.